# Rubik's cube 19 move Solution

Tags: rubiks-cube

All Rubik's cube positions can be solved in 20 moves or less; http://www.cube20.org/

What's one such position that requires 19 moves to solve, please give the faces, and the moves to solve.

Comment: The page you link to actually gives such a position, the "Superflip" in the applet at the top of the page (skip to the end to see the position).  More information is given in the "What are the Hardest Positions?" section.

Comment: @Arthur Snap never even saw that! Hold on...

Comment: "Other than the one given on the site" has now been added to the question

Comment: The site does also give a [list of all known distance-20 states](http://www.cube20.org/distance20s/).

Comment: Okay then... I'm terrible at this. Lemme change it to 19.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it has many answers and link is available from the OP himself.

Comment: I highly disagree with the reason this was closed.  It was a terrible question because it is essentially a duplicate of another question on this site (once you know the 20 solution already included the 19 is simple to find).  If it were the first question on this site, though, it would be on topic.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Given any position you know that has 20 moves (like the Superflip) just do one move towards the solution and you have a position that requires 19 moves.

Comment: To be more accurate, since the superflip is highly symmetrical: Take the superflip and make **any** move.

Answer (score 4):

Below sequence movement from a solved cube will make the position solvable in 19 moves

> F U' F2 D' B U R' F' L D' R' U' L U B' D2 R' F U2

And the solution would be

> Step 1: U2
>  Step 2: F'
>  Step 3: R
>  Step 4: D2 
>  Step 5: B 
>  Step 6: U' 
>  Step 7: L' 
>  Step 8: U 
>  Step 9: R 
>  Step10: D 
>  Step11: L' 
>  Step12: F 
>  Step13: R 
>  Step14: U' 
>  Step15: B' 
>  Step16: D 
>  Step17: F2 
>  Step18: U 
>  Step19: F'

Comment: Can you _prove_ it requires 19 moves though? That is that no 18- moves solution exists?

Comment: Yes, this is superflip config with one less twist. If this has a better solution, superflip would be solvable in fewer than 20 steps.

Comment: Ah, didn't realize this is superflip :) Roger that.